# Change User Agent When Adding Files via urlSource in js-ipfs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, node-https

I have a function to add files in `js-ipfs` via URL.

```js
async function addFile(url) {
  try {
    for await (const file of node.add(urlSource(url))) {
      console.log('Hash for ' + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error('Problem downloading: ' + e.toString());
  }
}
```

Some URLs that I pass in work great, while others will serve a file only to certain user agents. Is there a way to specify a custom user agent of "`Wget/`" on the HTTP GET requests done by IPFS `urlSource`?

**Edit**: After poking around the source of `js-ipfs` a bit, it looks like it's using [`node-fetch`](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) to make the request. I tried changing the line to:

```js
for await (const file of node.add(urlSource(url, {"headers": ["User-Agent", "Wget/"]}))) {
```

and

```js
for await (const file of node.add(urlSource(url, {"headers": {"User-Agent": "Wget/"}}))) {
```

based off of [the `node-fetch` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#new-headersinit), but no dice. Webhook.site still shows my requests having a user-agent of `node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)`.

Answer (score 0):

User **achingbrain** on [the IPFS forums](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/change-user-agent-when-adding-urlsource/7746/2?u=leoherzog) pointed out that the `options` object is currently [not passed into the `http` constructor](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-utils/blob/master/src/files/url-source.js#L8). I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-utils/pull/37) to modify this behavior.